# Not finding base url in zend 2 while using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

My domain pointing a location where a folder website exist. At here I have created a .htaccess file and write here rewrite rule to redirect to website folder when someone type domain in url,but when I do these config my application not working properly because it's not finding base url.

Folder structure is.

Folder-->website

Folder-->.htaccess

my domain point to Folder.

.htaccess file code is

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/website [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Can you add some example urls, indicating what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: when i use http://192.168.29.48/folder/website/ url its working fine but when i use http://192.168.29.48/folder/ it not working.